# Find all angles $\theta$ such that $x_1\cos(0)+x_2\cos(\theta)+x_3\cos(2\theta)+\dots + x_{n+1}\cos (n\theta)=0$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math

Find all angles $\theta$ such that $\exists x_1,x_2,\dots x_{n+1}, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$x_1\cos(0)+x_2\cos(\theta)+x_3\cos(2\theta)+\dots + x_{n+1}\cos (n\theta)=0,\\x_1\sin(0)+x_2\sin(\theta)+x_3\sin(2\theta)+\dots + x_{n+1}\sin(n\theta)=0.$$

Here is my progress. If $\theta$ satisfies then $180-\theta$ satisfies too. Clearly, angles of the form $\frac{360}{r}$ satisfy ( simply consider $r$ regular polygon with external angle $\frac{360}{r}$). For example, $\cos(0)+ \cos(60)+\cos(120)+\cos(180)+\cos(240)+\cos(300)=0$

I also got $\theta= 109.47$ or $\cos(\theta)=-1/3 $ satisfying with $3cos(0)+2\cos(\theta)+3\cos(2\theta)=0.$

Answer (score 4):

Multiply the sine equation by the imaginary unit $i$ and then add the two equations together. Using Euler's identity $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ we obtain the equivalent condition
$$x_1+x_2e^{i\theta}+x_3e^{2i\theta}+\dotsm+x_{n+1}e^{in\theta}=0.$$
But since $e^{in\theta} = (e^{i\theta})^n$, we can put $z=e^{i\theta}$ and the question becomes the following: for which complex $z$ on the unit circle are there integers $n,x_1,\dotsc, x_{n+1}$ such that
$$x_1+x_2z+x_3z^2+\dotsm+x_{n+1}z^n=0?$$
In other words, which complex $z$ on the unit circle are [algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number)? So far as I know, there isn't a nice characterization of these numbers. At any rate, the set of $\theta$ which satisfy your question is given by
$$S = \bigcup_{\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{C})\cap\{|z|=1\}}{\rm arg(z)}$$
where $\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{C})$ denotes the algebraic numbers of $\mathbb{C}$ and ${\rm arg}(z) = \{{\rm Arg}(z)+2\pi k:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

We can describe a (probably proper) subset of $S$ at least. If $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$, then it solves the problem. Indeed, we can write $\theta = 2\pi m/n$ for $m,n$ integers with $n$ positive and then $z=e^{i\theta}$ will be a solution of the polynomial equation $-1+z^n=0$.

Comment: Can you explain how $\theta=2\pi m/n$ solves will be a solution? And can you state what happens when we take $\theta$ as irrational?

Comment: If $\theta = 2\pi m/n$, then $(e^{i\theta})^n = e^{i2\pi m}$ by properties of exponents. But this is clearly $1$. Thus $e^{i\theta}$ is a solution to $z^n=1$, which rearranges to give $-1+z^n=0$.

As for when $\theta$ is irrational, who knows. As I said there isn't a nice characterization of algebraic numbers. In general $\theta$ irrational will probably not work but we cannot rule it out.

Comment: Surely if $w \in \mathbb{C}$ is algebraic, then so is $|w|=\sqrt{w^* w}\in\mathbb{R}_+$, and hence $z=w/|w|$ is algebraic and on the unit circle.  So the elements of $S$ are all of the form $(x+iy)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, where $x$ and $y$ are algebraic.

Comment: Sure, you can also write things in that form. I chose not to because it made the claim that $\mathbb{Q}\cdot\pi\subset S$ a bit more difficult to see. It also doesn't bring us any closer to determining what $S$ looks like since characterizing algebraic numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ is about as hard as characterizing them in $\mathbb{C}$.